# Get clicked item on QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt

```
class TreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:    

    TreeWidget(QWidget* parent = 0) : QTreeWidget(parent) 
    {
        connect(this, &QTreeWidget::itemClicked, this, &TreeWidget::onItemClicked);
    }


public slots:
    void onItemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column)
    {
        auto _item = dynamic_cast<QTreeWidgetItem*>(item);
        qDebug() << "item: " << item << " _item: << _item;
        // if (item == 0) { ... }
        // elseif ...
    }
}
```

I'm confused about how to get the clicked item of a `QTreeWidget`, in my example, `qDebug()` prints something like `item:  0x2a64e3edfb0` what is the 'proper' way to read it?

I'm trying to perform different actions according to the item clicked.

Comment: 1st: What is the intention to convert a `QTreeWidgetItem*` to `QTreeWidgetItem*`? 2nd: A `QTreeWidgetItem*` is what it pretends to be, i.e. literally a pointer to a [QTreeWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html). To _read it_, you can use everything what the API (or the doc.) offers for it.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat isnt possible to convert `item` to a 'readable' `int`, like 0 1 2 3? how do i compare the `QTreeWidgetItem* item` with a specific item index?

Comment: why did you cast the item to `QTreeWidgetItem`? It is QTreeWidgetItem when you click on it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R i was just confused/testing, you can ignore that line, i removed it.

Comment: If you need the model index associated with the item just use the appropriate signal: [`QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#clicked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `item:  0x2a64e3edfb0` is your object and **0x2a64e3edfb0** is your object's address in memory.

But your QTreeWidgetItem object has functions and properties like its text and you can get it like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)
{

    qDebug() << "item: " << item <<","<<item->text(column);


}
```

For get the Index of QTreeWidgetItem you should get it from your parent means `QTreeWidget`

like this :

```
void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)
{

    qDebug() << "item: " <<ui->treeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);

}
```

the output :

[image]

**If item is a child of a branch  then you can use this:**

```
 qDebug() << "item: " <<ui->treeWidget->indexFromItem(item,column).row();
```

Look at  [QTreeWidget::indexFromItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html#indexFromItem) function.

Comment: Thank you, Parisa! is it possible to get the item index instead of the text?

Comment: @touraille I update my answer. you inherit from `QTreeWidget` so you should use your parent function means `parent()->indexOfTopLevelItem(item)`

Comment: When the item is a child of a branch its returning -1, which is the correct function in this case?

Comment: @touraille I update my answer. you need  `ui->treeWidget->indexFromItem(item,column).row()`

Comment: on a branch containing two children `ui->treeWidget->indexFromItem(item,column).row()` prints 0 and 1 respectively, how do I also get the branch index?

Comment: @touraille I didn't understand can you provide an example? and also it is another question I think we should go to another thread because readers of this question may be confused in future

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249180/discussion-between-touraille-and-parisa-h-r).